# Getting current user with a sql trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql trigger for one of my tables. I'm just wondering if its possible that i can track and add the user that makes a change to the table?

See code below

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Trigger_Audit_Client] on [dbo].[Client] for insert, update, delete
as
declare @type varchar(1) ,
@UpdateDate datetime

if exists (select * from inserted) and exists (select * from deleted)
    select @type = 'U'
else if exists (select * from inserted)
    select @type = 'I'
else
    select @type = 'D'

select  @UpdateDate = getdate()

insert  Client_Audit (Client_Id, ClientName, ClientSurname, TelephoneHome, TelephoneWork, TelephoneCellular, DOB, Gender, ClientIdNumber, Company_Id, Region, City, Email, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Will_UID, WillCreated, WillLatest, UpdateDate, UpdateType)
select  Client_Id, ClientName, ClientSurname, TelephoneHome, TelephoneWork, TelephoneCellular, DOB, Gender, ClientIdNumber, Company_Id, Region, City, Email, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Will_UID, WillCreated, WillLatest, @UpdateDate, @type + '_old'
from deleted
insert  Client_Audit (Client_Id, ClientName, ClientSurname, TelephoneHome, TelephoneWork, TelephoneCellular, DOB, Gender, ClientIdNumber, Company_Id, Region, City, Email, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Will_UID, WillCreated, WillLatest, UpdateDate, UpdateType)
select  Client_Id, ClientName, ClientSurname, TelephoneHome, TelephoneWork, TelephoneCellular, DOB, Gender, ClientIdNumber, Company_Id, Region, City, Email, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Will_UID, WillCreated, WillLatest, @UpdateDate, @type + '_new'
from inserted
```

Comment: Aside: always use `SET NOCOUNT ON` within your triggers. See my answer for some alternative code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User_Name()`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx

### Syntax

```
USER_NAME ( [ id ] )
```

> When id is omitted, the current user in the current context is assumed. If the parameter contains the word NULL will return NULL.When USER_NAME is called without specifying an id after an EXECUTE AS statement, USER_NAME returns the name of the impersonated user. If a Windows principal accesses the database by way of membership in a group, USER_NAME returns the name of the Windows principal instead of the group.

## ASIDE:

I would change your trigger code to this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.Client_Audit (Cliend_Id, ClientName, ..., UpdateDate, UpdateType)
SELECT Coalesce(i.Cliend_Id, d.Cliend_Id) As Cliend_Id
     , Coalesce(i.ClientName, d.ClientName) As ClientName
     , ...
     , Current_Timestamp As UpdateDate
     , CASE WHEN i.Cliend_Id IS NULL THEN 'D'
            WHEN d.Cliend_Id IS NULL THEN 'I'
            ELSE 'U'
       END As UpdateType
FROM   inserted As i
 FULL
  JOIN deleted As d
    ON d.Cliend_Id = i.Cliend_Id;
```

Does the same thing but in a cleaner manner (no extra logic and variables, just a single statement).

Any questions just ask!

Comment: FYI: `Current_User` is equivalent to `User_Name()` and both are available in SQL Server 2005-2012  :)

Comment: yup, looks like you beat me to the answer. Also yours is formatted better and is easier to read +1

Comment: Please see @Roman_Pekar's answer - User_name() will give dbo if in sysadmin role

Answer (score 13):

Use [system_user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) or [suser_name()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) for that.

[user_name()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx) will return `dbo` if your user is in sysadmin role.

Comment: If you use system_user, it adds the domain name to the username at least in my case. i.e. `domain_name\user_name`

Answer (score 1):

Current_user is what you are looking for good sir (depending on what version of sql-server you are running)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new table and populate it with a trigger, for example:

```
create trigger LogTrigger
ON YourTable 
FOR INSERT
as
insert into LogTable  (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, DataInsert, UserName) 
    select Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, GETDATE(), User_Name() 
from inserted
```