# Retrieve deletedBy in the DELETE Trigger at record deletion

Tags: sql-server

I have a table. I'm using trigger to log the changes of records. There is a field name "updatedBy" which is logged the person who perform the operation (for example insert,update,delete)

It is fine for insert and update, as I will insert or update the field together with the other parameters, for example

```
INSERT INTO T (P1,UPDATEDBY) SELECT 'HELLO','ME'
UPDATE T SET P1 ='WORLD', UPDATEDBY = 'ME'
```

For those operations, I can find out 'ME' has inserted/updated the records so I can create log correctly. However, how to tell the database who deleted the record? Since I'm just executing

```
DELETE FROM T WHERE P1='WORLD'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Title is updated.

Comment: Do you have a separate audit table to store deleted rows?

Comment: I have another table to store full operation, but the main issue is I couldn't update the updatedBy field during record deletion, I have to implement it on top of the record delete SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

then you need one more table that save activity log for CRUD(CReate,Update,Delete)

with atleast 3 parameter

- name
- date
- action

and then just insert into this table whenever you do CRUD action or atleast for delete case only

Comment: But then it is violate my original design, if I create one more table to store the CRUD, then I need to executing it on top of delete operation. It is the same as I insert it directly to the log table (which means i dont need to create one more table for it). My main problem is rather it is possible to udpate the updatedBy during deletion:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the changes of record better use the Magic Tables (Inserted, Deleted) available in SQL Server. These two tables will have the details about inserted, deleted and updated records.

Please follow the link for reference,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93126e/what-are-the-magic-tables-used-by-triggers-in-sql-server/

[What are the magic tables available in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851189/what-are-the-magic-tables-available-in-sql-server-2000)

Or If you want to take the current user then

[Getting current user with a sql trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535074/getting-current-user-with-a-sql-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting through application in ado.net or entity framework, There is no way to track who deleted the record, there is one simple trick that you can use as I did and it is working perfectly fine with minimum changes and no extra column into the tables.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[CreateLogCart]
on [dbo].[Cart]
after UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
as
declare @targetID bigint,
@user int, 
@activity varchar(10);
if exists(SELECT 1 from inserted) and exists (SELECT 1 from deleted)
begin
    SET @activity = 'UPDATE';
    **-- update createdby before delete and do not log**-----------------------------
    declare @iby int;
    declare @dby int;
    **-- update createdvy before delete and do not log**------------------------------
    SELECT @targetID = d.CartId, @dby = d.CreatedBy from deleted d;
    SELECT @user = d.modifiedby, @iby = d.CreatedBy from inserted d;

    if(@iby = @dby) **-- update createdby before delete and do not log** --------
    begin
      INSERT into AuditCart(CartId, UserId, AppId, Description, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, Activity, ActivityBy, ActivityOn)
    select @targetID, d.userid, d.AppId, d.Description, d.CreatedBy, d.CreatedOn, d.ModifiedBy, d.ModifiedOn, @activity, @user, getdate() from deleted d
    end

end

If exists (Select 1 from inserted) and not exists(Select 1 from deleted)
begin
    SET @activity = 'INSERT';
    SELECT @targetID = i.CartId from inserted i;
    SELECT @user = d.modifiedby from inserted d;
     INSERT into AuditCart(CartId, UserId, AppId, Description, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, Activity, ActivityBy, ActivityOn)
     select @targetID, d.userid, d.AppId, d.Description, d.CreatedBy, d.CreatedOn, d.ModifiedBy, d.ModifiedOn, @activity, @user, getdate() from inserted d
end

If exists(select 1 from deleted) and not exists(Select 1 from inserted)
begin 
    **-- revert createdby updated in delete operation**--------------
    declare @cby int;
     SET @cby = (select top 1 CreatedBy from dbo.AuditCart where Activity = 'INSERT' and CartId = (select d.CartId from deleted d) order by CreatedOn desc);  
    **-- revert createdby updated in delete operation**-------------

    SET @activity = 'DELETE';
    SELECT @targetID = i.CartId from deleted i;
    SELECT @user = d.CreatedBy from deleted d;
    INSERT into AuditCart(CartId, UserId, AppId, Description, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, Activity, ActivityBy, ActivityOn)
    select @targetID, d.userid, d.AppId, d.Description, ****@cby****, d.CreatedOn, d.ModifiedBy, d.ModifiedOn, @activity, @user, getdate() from deleted d
end
```

You just need to update createdby before delete and do not log it in update trigger as I put if condition in update trigger, 
Now in delete trigger you just need to revert it by getting createdby from old log of insert, after taking its value in who deletedby valiable as **activityby** in my case